# Use Per Customer without Coupon Code

Tags: magento-1.9, coupon-codes

I am using magento 1.9 for my website and I wish to set one time promotion without Coupon Code. So I have set "Use Per Customer" to 1 with "No Coupon". But customer can still use this promotion multiple time with Paypal Checkout. Is "Use Per Customer"  function only work with Coupon Code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you choose for customer groups? All customers?

Comment: I do not choose all customer. My website have membership and online account customer and guest. So I choose the membership and online account for customer group as I noticed "Use per Customer" is only work with login customer.

Answer (score 1):

In app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Validator.php it clearly checks for rules with no coupons and checks what the uses per customer is set to and if this customer is over that limit.

```
    /**

     * check per rule usage limit

     */

    $ruleId = $rule->getId();

    if ($ruleId && $rule->getUsesPerCustomer()) {

        $customerId     = $address->getQuote()->getCustomerId();

        $ruleCustomer   = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule_customer');

        $ruleCustomer->loadByCustomerRule($customerId, $ruleId);

        if ($ruleCustomer->getId()) {

            if ($ruleCustomer->getTimesUsed() >= $rule->getUsesPerCustomer()) {

                $rule->setIsValidForAddress($address, false);

                return false;

            }

        }

    }
```

So either you have some 3rd party module extending/rewriting this model or your rule is not properly set up?

If you add some debug to this code you should get the answer to your question.

Comment: I have checked the 3rd part module but it not rewriting this model. I have found that salesrule_coupon_usage table is not updated.

Comment: What module? Try disabling and see if the usage table gets updated? What happens when you mage::log the function above?

Comment: Hi Hiam, Thanks for your prompt reply. Its Amasty extension . When I disable module, I can't set any promotion rule as all settings gone. Is that mean  Amasty extension have some issue?

Comment: @user1846754 Amasty has a conflict detector - does it report any conflicts? After you disabled it, did you flush cache?

Comment: Yes I flush cache after disable. salesrule_customer and salesrule_coupon_usage is only not updated if customer use paypal. Credit card payment is ok